How to install downloaded chrome extension using puppeteer?
I made an attempt to auto install chrome extension whenever I create a chrome account.
However, it doesn't work properly.
const extension = "D:/Program/chrome_extension/{path}";  //crx file path
    try {
        console.log("Opening the browser......");
        browser = await puppeteer.launch({
            headless: false,
            defaultViewport: null,  
            executablePath: 'C:\\Program Files\\Google\\Chrome\\Application\\chrome.exe',
            args: [
                '--start-maximized',
                `--disable-extensions-except=${extension }`,
                `--load-extension=${extension }`,
                '--enable-automation'
            ]        
        });
    } catch (err) {
        console.log("Could not create a browser instance => : ", err);
    }

I tried to use extension folder that is already installed, but it also didn't work.

Is "D:/Program/chrome_extension/{path}" really your code? If so, it should use backticks, template literal syntax: \D:/Program/chrome_extension/${path}``.
